# Where can I find Armand Krishnan, Marvin de Luca, and Lei Ying Lo?

Tags: evil-genius

I'm in the first level of the campaign, and one of the objectives is to find these three criminal masterminds in different part of the world.

So...what do I do? There are no instructions beyond that. I don't know how to look for them in the first place, so I don't know how I'd be able to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game doesn't tell you where they are but if you plot around in different areas you will stumble onto them. This method could take a long time so here is their locations:

```
Armand Krishnan - Indian Subcontinent
Marvin de Luca - North America (West Coast)
Lei Ying Lo - China and South East Asia (near the technician hostage)
```

Taken from the Evil Genius wiki:
http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Objective_2

I found this part personally frustrating because the game gives you no clue where to find them. There is more people you need to find later but I'll let you find out where they are on your own (or cheat and just follow the link...)

Comment: Does this mean I should set my minions to "Plot" rather than "Steal"?

Comment: @StrixVaria Yes, plotting helps uncover new missions. In case it isn't mentioned in the game, each minion type performs differently on the world map. Soldiers tend to steal the best, scientists plot the best, and social minions tend to keep the heat down. Try sending a few scientists out where Dycker mentioned.